# How to prevent manual resizing of md-input-container

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a textarea that resides inside md-input-container(using angularjs material version 1.1.12). I want to prevent users from resizing it and found md-no-resize property for this purpose in AngularJS Material docs. But this does not seem to work. I also tried adding style="resize:none" to the inner textarea but that did not work either. I would really appreciate if someone can suggest a way.
Thanks!

```
<div layout="column" style="width: 400px;">
  <md-input-container md-no-resize="true" style="width: 380px; height: 200px; padding: 10px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <textarea ng-model="x"/>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Comment: The "textarea" element is resizable by default. You have to change this behavior in CSS: textarea {  resize: none; }

Comment: Hard to tell without a working example, but you could try setting min- and max-width and height as workaround. Or resize:none with !important, to make sure it's not being overridden at some other point.

Comment: Many thanks guys! I could not make it with css. Please see my comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried something like this:

```
<md-input-container md-no-resize="true" style="width: 380px; height: 200px; padding: 10px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <textarea ng-model="x" md-no-resize/>
</md-input-container>
```

Here is the doc about it https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdInput

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was keeping to wrap textarea with md-resize-wrapper. I found the code below in angular-material.js. So adding md-no-resize just to textarea worked. Can you also edit the answer that way please?

Comment: function attachResizeHandle() {
        if (attr.hasOwnProperty('mdNoResize')) return;

Comment: Hi, could you edit my answer please, because I m not sure I exactly understand what you mean, if no could you provide a codepen and I ll paste it :)